# How to obtain state token for password reset in Okta

Tags: node.js, okta, okta-api

I want to implement forgot password feature using the following api in Okta
[Password Reset api](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/authn.html#reset-password)

For this api I need **State Token**.

So my question is How I can obtain state token in Okta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the forgot password requests: https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/authn.html#forgot-password

From there you can send the user the token, and they will be able to use this to reset their password. (you could also use 'change_password')

Comment: Can you provide example for `Forgot Password with Trusted Application`

Comment: There is an example in the doc, are you looking for something more specific ?

Comment: Thanks I used this `https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/authn#forgot-password-with-email-factor`